From Minimax to MILP
Definitions
Let

$S = \{ (x, y) | Ax + Dy \leqslant b\}$, and $\pi$ be its dual; And
$P_2(x) = \min_{(x, y) \in S} c^T_2 y$;

Problem
We aim to solve the following MILP.
$P = \max_{(x, y) \in S} c^T_1 x$
s.t.

$c^T_2 y = P_2(x) \geqslant T$;
$x \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

Where $T$ is a constant.
The above problem is a MiniMax problem where the corresponding $y$ solution must be an optimal $P_2(x)$.
KKT
The Lagrangian function of $P_2(x)$ is of the form
$\mathcal{L}_2(y, \pi) = c^T_2 y + \pi^T (Ax + Dy - b)$.
Note that, here $x$ is a parameter, and thus a constant.
Which KKT conditions state that:

Stationarity: $\nabla_y \mathcal{L}_2 = c^T_2 + \pi^T D = 0$;
Primal feasibility: $\nabla_{\pi} \mathcal{L}_2 = Ax + Dy - b \leqslant 0$;
Dual feasibility: $\pi \geqslant 0$; And
Orthogonality: $\pi \circ \nabla_{\pi} \mathcal{L}_2 = \pi \circ (Ax + Dy - b) = 0$.

MILP
The above conditions can be expressed in another MILP.
$P^{'} = \min c^T_1 x$
s.t.

$c^T_2 y \geqslant T$;
$c^T_2 = - \pi^T D$;
$- z M \leqslant Ax + Dy - b \leqslant 0$;
$0 \leqslant \pi \leqslant (1 - z) M$;
$z \in \mathbb{B}^m$; And
$x \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

My question is: $P = P^{'}$?

I'm not sure this is a minmax (or maxmin) problem as stated. Assume
$S$ is bounded and let $S_{x}$ be the project of $S$ on $\mathbb{N}^{n}.$
You can just maximize $c_{1}^{T}x$ over $S_{x}$ and then, given
optimal solution $x^{},$ solve $P_{2}(x^{}).$ The resulting solution
$y^{}$ will by definition satisfy $P_{2}(x^{})=c_{2}^{T}y^{*}.$
In other words, the inner problem does not constrain the outer problem,
other than requiring the inequality constraint to hold for some $y$.

Thank you so much. I did a mistake, because, I also wanted to impose the constraint $c^T_2 y = P_2(x) \geqslant T$.

Sorry for the late continuation. But I found the material for it. According to slide 47 of alop.uni-trier.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/course-Alop-102020-MLabbe.pdf, and the following related content: math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722032, and math.stackexchange.com/questions/502227, the above transformation is right.
